# How to bring application to foreground in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

I am detecting for iBeacon in background. When my device comes in a particular region application should comes to foreground.

Comment: all you can with public API is post local notification

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It cannot be done without user interaction. The only option is you can generate a push notification to tell the user to bring the application to foreground.

This is from the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) about this issue:

> When the operating system delivers  push notification (iOS or OS X)
>   and the target application is not running in the foreground, it
>   presents the notification (alert, icon badge number, sound). If there
>   is a notification alert and the user taps or clicks the action button
>   (or moves the action slider), the application launches and calls a
>   method to pass in the local-notification object or remote-notification
>   payload. If the application is running in the foreground when the
>   notification is delivered, the application delegate receives a local
>   or push notification.

Comment: This is correct.  Any dfoyubters can see my failed attempt to force an app to the foreground here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/22230693/1461050. It is worthy of note that Android does allow this.

Comment: Thanks @Khawar Ali for you help. Done the same thing you mentioned.

Comment: Its is possible because when Whatsapp Call receive  and app close its come to foreground
AND WHEN app in backgroud and whatapp call receive app auto come to foregroud

Comment: @Shakell Ahmed do you have an idea how to deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

To answer to some comments about WhatsApp, with it, when you receive a classic vocal call, IOS use CallKit to display your call and wake up your phone, but it's not inside app. I try to make a video call with WhatsApp, and in this case, there is a notification. Press notification open app and answer to the call.

Conclusion : It's impossible to wake up app from background to foreground in IOS, but it's not really a problem because you can use notification to display what you want and get the user to your app after a touch on your notification. All of iPhone users are familiar with this kind of interaction, it's better to deal with it.

Comment: Okay, then how to do something like whatsApp. How to show callkit notiifcaton and screen at the same time?