# iOS:how schedule the app from background to foreground

Tags: ios, background, schedule, foreground, background-foreground

I am coding for connection between iPhone and my smart watch by bluetooth low energy. The functionality is "find my phone", touching the watch then iPhone will alarm. During the process, I want to my app will being active. It can be scheduled to the foreground from the background, so we can do more other thing! But I am not able to find the api about it, anyone can help me, thanks?

Comment: Why does it need to come to foreground?

Answer (score 0):

You can not force an application to bring it to foreground.

Please see this answer for help.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22930371/1891327