# Force a sequence of methods to perform on a background thread

Tags: ios, multithreading

My app performs a background fetch, in which it does a series of communications with a web service, and posts local notifications if there's some new information.

I have an umbrella method, called **GetEverything**, that starts this chain of logging in, getting, posting, processing data, etc. This is the method that is called upon a background fetch.

**GetEverything** can also be triggered by a user in the foreground. In that case it always works as expected.

When **GetEverything** is called from the background fetch, is gets stuck on individual parts of the **GetEverything** chain. Some of the spawned threads just hang. Only when I bring the app to the foreground, they resume.

To solve this, I forced **GetEverything** to a low-prio thread:

```
- (void)GetEverything:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
       //my chain of events;

    });
}
```

That helped a lot, but still, I had to get deeper into the chain, to pinpoint other methods, and force them on low priority as well.

One example of a method in my chain that pops back to the main thread is

```
-(NSString*) deleteHTMLfrom: (NSString*) htmlString {         
    if (![htmlString isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){


        NSAttributedString* attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                              options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                                                        NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                                                                   documentAttributes:nil
                                                                                error:nil];
        NSString* plainText = [attributedText string];
        return plainText;
    }
    return htmlString;
}
```

My question:
how to I force all the 'links' of my chain to perform on a background thread?

Comment: Have you called `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` before you call `getEverything`?

Comment: @Paulw11 I guess that my lack of knowledge of this is the reason for my question. I'm reading documentation right now. Would beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler be the magic trick that I need?

Comment: You need to ensure that all of your tasks are finished before you return from the background fetch delegate method, and if they haven't then you need to have told iOS that background tasks are still running - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39197933/how-to-troubleshoot-ios-background-app-fetch-not-working/39219264#39219264