# How to bring IOS app from background to foreground without using local notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios10

Is there any way to bring the app to foreground which is running in background without sending any local notification?

Comment: No, there isn't

Comment: You can't do this.

Comment: there is only a way to do so by tapping on notification whether it is push or local notif.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bring application to foreground in ios?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930259/how-to-bring-application-to-foreground-in-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for you to programatically foreground the app. If you think about it, allowing developers to do that could have significant consequences to user experience.

Comment: then it could be in a comment section you have enough rep for that.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see a reason this should go as a comment as it's an answer to the question. Feel free to futher voice your thoughts.

Answer (score -1):

There must be a way to simulate it.

Uber Driver's App launch when the user gets a new ride with app in background.
WhatsApp in background opens a phone view when somebody calls the user.