# A way to bring a minimized flutter app to foreground

Tags: android, ios, flutter

how can I Navigate to a new screen and popup application from background service when app is invisible ?

I know how easy it is to navigate from one route to another in Flutter. We just need to do push and pop but Want to bring my app foreground based on server data i'm running background job for updating user location, Read the documentation but nothing explains how to bring Flutter app to foreground even if mobile screen is off or my flutter app is in background :)?

Comment: I have same problm ! and I think no way for now ! you dont have any way and it is very bad :( .

Comment: maybe used native code in flutter ! not official way

Comment: Here I have answered this question on another thread. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61709376/9949983 check it out

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [app_to_foreground](https://pub.dev/packages/app_to_foreground) plugin.

It only works for android

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this plugin for doing anything that you want in your project flutter_foreground_task

[you can find it here:](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_service/)

Answer (score -1):

use this plugin - https://github.com/sunsetjesus/flutter_intent

**usage -**

```
FlutterIntent.openApp('app.package.name','app.package.name.MainActivity');
```