# Flutter - Automatically run the application when notification received from FCM (without clicking it)

Tags: flutter, push-notification

I'm developing a delivery app, when the client orders something i want the supplier app to open up on screen with 2 buttons to **accept** or **decline** the order.

its easy to do when the supplier clicks the notification (`onLaunch` and `onResume` configuration), but i want it to happen **without their interaction.**

Something like when someone **calls you on whatsapp** or **FB messanger**.

is this achievable ? couldnt find such a thing in flutter.

Comment: why cannot you provide those two actions as part of your notification when app is in background?. Foreground you an trigger the alert from onMessageReceived.

Comment: Suggestion here, Create a broadcast receiver to read a notification. If the notification received from your product you can open your app and can show the alert on start. But your supplier should give you permission to read the notification.

Comment: I'm also looking for this have you get anything about it?

Comment: I don't think this is possible on iOS (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930259/how-to-bring-application-to-foreground-in-ios/22930371#22930371) and I doubt it is possible on android. Regardless, it is a bad user experience and I would advise you to proceed with requiring a user interaction unless you implement a direct caller into the app.

Comment: Do we have any updates or suggestions here I am also finding a way to open an app without clicking on notification. Please provide suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

```
      AndroidNotificationDetails(
                      'full screen channel id',
                      'full screen channel name',
                      'full screen channel description',
                      priority: Priority.high,
                      importance: Importance.high,
                      fullScreenIntent: true),
```

this will open app for android

Answer (score -2):

Note: This old way for implementing the the FCM Notification,

As for the the Documentation, Notification come your app, either it is in foreground or background.
But in these case of Background:  A notification is delivered to the device's system tray and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

Case of Foreground: You can navigate to any screen. with help of

```
final FirebaseMessaging fcmMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
 
fcmMessaging.configure(

onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
            print("onMessage: $message");
        },

onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
            print("onLaunch: $message");
            // your code 
        },

onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
            print("onResume: $message");
            
        },
);
```

New way : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73221621/5197656

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at the [`firebase_messaging`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) docs where it explains how to setup background messages on `Optionally handle background messages`