# IOS7 iBeacon: How to launch app when detect a beacon(app not running)

Tags: ios7, ibeacon

I have managed to implement CLLocationManagerDelegate and in didDetermineState I can send a notification when the app is not running.

Now I want is to launch the app immediately as soon as it enters a particular region. How could I do that?

Thanks heaps in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot launch the app UI when a beacon is detected because of iOS restrictions.  The closest you can do is to send a local notification on beacon detection, giving the user a message and allowing the user to choose to launch the app UI by tapping on this notification.

See here for a more detailed explanation: 
[Can I launch an app in Foreground when I enter an iBeacon range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224639/can-i-launch-an-app-in-foreground-when-i-enter-an-ibeacon-range)

Comment: Thanks! According to that link, what about this:
(3) through a custom URL to launch the app from a different app.
I haven't tested. Will update once I got result.