# Is it possible to get an app to open up when entering a beacon region / within range of a beacon/ibeacon

Tags: ibeacon, user-experience, android-ibeacon

I'm exploring the end user experience for a beacon prototype but I'm struggling to find any end-user scenarios that involve the app becoming active / opening up on the screen when within range.

I can get the app to send a notification and this is the most likely experience on both Android and iOS but does anyone know if it is possible to get the app to open up?

It's unlikely that I'd want real customers to have their experience interfered with in this way, I think it's ok if the app is already running and is open but not if it's running but not open.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On Android this is possible.  The [reference app](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference) for the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) demonstrates how to do exactly this.

On iOS, it is not possible due to OS security restrictions. [See here for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224639/can-i-launch-an-app-in-foreground-when-i-enter-an-ibeacon-range) The best you can do is send a local notification to the user when the beacon is detected, then if the user gestures to it, bring up the app.