# How can wake up(or start) my app from background(not running)? ios - ibeacon - iphone

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

Important: IOS support wake(start) apps when apps not running.

I build a ibeacon app. This is work good . When app is not runnig IOS wake up my app and my app give notification. when app is not runnig, ios run  this function (in background) is working

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion!) {


    var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.alertAction = "iBeacon notification."
    localNotification.alertBody = "Detect a signal."
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

}
```

I wanna write a code as "start my app" in this code block ? 
Like

```
app.start() or  app.wakeup()
```

Is it possible?

```
if(answer == yes){how can i do?}
```

Comment: Do you mean bring your app to the foreground?  If so then no, you can't do that. Only the user can by tapping your notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible on iOS.  The operating system has restrictions that prevent an app from bringing itself to the foreground unless a user explicitly gestures for it to do so.

For a demonstration of how this does not work, and the alternatives, please see my similar answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22230693/1461050