# iBeacon possible to wake up an app?

Tags: iphone, ibeacon

We have requirement to integrate ibeacon in our iphone app.When user reached nearest to a beacon ,

1)App need to wake up and open automatically.Is it possible? 
or
2)We need a local notification first and click on it will open the app?

First one is possible , help is highly appreciable

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open an app on iOS automatically on beacon detection.   The most you can do is send a local notification, and if the user taps on that, the app will launch.

See here for details:  [Can I launch an app in Foreground when I enter an iBeacon range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224639/can-i-launch-an-app-in-foreground-when-i-enter-an-ibeacon-range)